# Webform CiviCRM Case Tokens

Tags: webform-civicrm, civicase

Has anybody had success in using the CiviCRM Webform Case autocomplete tokens? We are using the cases for case management and would like to give users an option to update an existing case via a custom URL in a webform. It works for one user but does not work for another. Is there some permissions missing? Currently using ?case1=1 for Case ID one to prepopulate in the form. This works. But once I go to case1=4 or 5 it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

> But once I go to case1=4 or 5 it does not work

The case loaded on the webform is specified by passing the id in the form of `case{fieldset}=<case_id>`.

For eg loading case id = 1 on fieldset 2 would be done by adding case2=1 in the URL.

Also make sure the contact loaded on the same fieldset is a client of the case. For eg - if contact A is attached to caseid = 2. Add this in the URL to load the case on the form =

```
webform_url?cid1=<contact_id>&case1=<case_id>
```

Similarly, if case is loaded on fieldset 2, the url would be -

```
webform_url?cid2=<contact_id>&case2=<case_id>
```

Comment: Thanks Jitendra. That mostly seems to work. However, when I am trying to update the case it is using my account instead of the cid account or signed in user account. Any ideas?

Comment: Edit the component of the contact in the webform, i.e, From the webform tab, click edit link on the existing contact component which is loading your contact id, and check whether you have enabled any default value for the same.